# Building go linker as a stand alone tool

Tags: c, macos, linker, go, executable

I was browsing the go source and I wanted to build it as a standalone linker for osx that can generate mach-o files. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: There is already a standalone linker, invoked by `go build`. Check the output of `go tool 6l -h`.

Comment: Not quite sure why you tagged this with "c"... are you asking a question about generating a standalone binary with cgo?

Comment: @nemo No I mean taking the source code from the linker in the `go build` tool and making it its own separate question

Comment: @user3131007 but it *is* already a separate tool. `go tool` is just a fancy way to run it. Check the output of `go tool -n 6l`.

Comment: @nemo But can I get the source code of those linkers independently?

Comment: Why do you want to use this tool directly anyway?  For cross-compilation by any chance?

Comment: @kostix I want to build a programming language that can natively compile to multiple systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker is already a standalone tool. You can see it by running

```
go tool -n 6l
```

which will print the location of  the `6l` (x86 64 bit linker) executable.

The source code of `6l` can be found in [`GOROOT/src/cmd/6l`](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/cmd/6l?name=go1.2.1).

In that directory you can use `make` to build it.

Comment: Notice that the linker is called 8l for i386 and 5l for ARM. This is the Plan 9 naming convention where the first letter indicates the architecture (e.g. 6 for amd64, 1 for 68k, 5 for arm, ...) and the second letter indicates the tool (l for linker, c for C-compiler, g for Go-compiler).